# How to use new automapper (v4) mapping configuration?

Tags: c#, automation, mapping, automapper, blazy

How to use new automapper v4 configs ? An ex:

```
MapperConfiguration mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<PersonModel, Person>());

mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<PersonModel, Person>());
```

But this is not the way as you can see. I'm creating new MapperConfiguration again, so first configuration will be gone. I'm a little bit tried now maybe I'm not carefull but it looks complex to me.

Old times, you can do that;

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<PersonModel, Person>();
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simple, sorry. Here is the code;

```
MapperConfiguration mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<PersonModel, Person>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Person, PersonModel>();
});
```